# Phonegap how to come back to app screen and exit from app iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I am creating a phonegap application that posts the login information to my website. When user signs off I want to come back to my app. Do I just send the url location along with the post data so that I can come back? or there is another elegant way?

Also when user clicks on the iphone home button, I want the application to exit. Currently it just saves the session and the page and goes back directly to the page if I start the application again.

I am using adobe phonegap site to build and test the application

Comment: what about posting some code?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I assume that you are navigating the Phonegap WebView (which is running your app) to the URL of your website? 
If so, at this point you no longer have an app to navigate back to - the WebView has lost its handle on your app. In order to "navigate back" to your app, you should use the [InAppBrowser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/doc/index.md) to navigate to your website. This will allow you to return to your app after the user logs out from your website. You'll need to somehow communicate the logout from your website in the InAppBrowser WebView to your app in its WebView. You may be able to achieve this with [cross window messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

You can't "exit" an app in iOS - the OS does not allow you to do this. The best you can do is use the [resume event](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#resume) to detect when your app has been restored from the background, then manually reset your app to its initial state.